# Error ocurring while deploying asp mvc web application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I made a simple Classroom asp.net MVC 5 web application and I'm using the default account controller and account class for log in.
When I try to run it in debug mode using visual studio, everything is perfectly fine. but when I deploy it using "Web Deploy" and checking "code first migration at the application start, I'm successfully re-directed to localhost/home but as soon as I try go to login page or register page and try to login this error shows up and I'm totally clueless what is going wrong. I have tried a lot options I found on different forums to fix this but to no success.

this is the error code I'm getting.

```
Server Error in '/home' Application.

Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification      starting at index 0. 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the     current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0.

Source Error: 


Line 77:             // This doesn't count login failures towards account   lockout
Line 78:             // To enable password failures to trigger account     lockout, change to shouldLockout: true
Line 79:             var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
Line 80:             switch (result)
Line 81:             {

    Source File: D:\Release 1    \Zip\ClassRoom\ClassRoom\Controllers\AccountController.cs    Line: 79 

Stack Trace: 


    [ArgumentException: Format of the initialization string does not conform to  specification starting at index 0.]
       System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions.GetKeyValuePair(String connectionString, Int32 currentPosition, StringBuilder buffer, Boolean useOdbcRules, String& keyname, String& keyvalue) +1985
   System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions.ParseInternal(Hashtable parsetable, String connectionString, Boolean buildChain, Hashtable synonyms, Boolean firstKey) +197
```

Comment: This suggests a problem with the connection string. Can you paste your connection string in your question?

Comment: You will want to make sure that your default connection string in the web config is set correctly on the server you have used web deploy to push this too.

Answer (score 0):

Hi this exception will occur when there is any kind of problem with the connection string . kindly check it again. Here is the some syntax reference

**SQL Server 2012**

Standard Security

```
Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;
```

Trusted Connection

```
Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;Trusted_Connection=True;
Connection to a SQL Server instance
```

The server/instance name syntax used in the server option is the same for all SQL Server connection strings.

```
Server=myServerName\myInstanceName;Database=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;
Password=myPassword;
```

**SQL Server 2005**

Standard Security

```
Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;
```

Trusted Connection

```
Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;Trusted_Connection=True;
Connection to a SQL Server instance
```

The server/instance name syntax used in the server option is the same for all SQL Server connection strings.

```
Server=myServerName\myInstanceName;Database=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword
```

Hope the above information was helpful

thanks
Karthik